# typescript ignore window unknown property

Tags: javascript, typescript, ethereum, metamask

I have a dapp that uses the MetaMask wallet extension, so I use `window.ethereum` a lot and get `Property 'ethereum' does not exist on type 'Window & typeof globalThis'.ts(2339)` a lot. How do I tell typescript to either ignore this or allow ther `ethereum` property  without use `// @ts-ignore`?

Answer (score 0):

The most obvious thing to do is to fix it with these type guards:

```
if (typeof window !== 'undefined' && typeof window.ethereum !== 'undefined') {
  // do something with window.ethereum
}
```

If you're using this in a lot of places, it makes more sense to define a property on the Window interface:

```
import ethThing from 'your-meta-mask/thing';

interface Window {
  ethereum: typeof ethThing;
}

// no TS error
window.ethereum.something();
```

The failing of the latter is a lack of runtime checking. You could of course use both in order to have typing and runtime checking.

2022-02-09 Edit:
What I was trying to get at with asking if you'd done a manual "TS check" is to figure out what conditions this is failing under. It may be that (A) static checking is failing in your IDE, (B) the build is failing, (C) you're somehow not getting that message until runtime. My assumption was (A).

Running the TypeScript compiler in a terminal will isolate it from anything that may be broken in the IDE. You can do so with a command similar to:

```
cd /path/to/your/project

# if you restore your tsconfig
./node_modules/typescript/bin/tsc --noEmit -p tsconfig.json

# using index.ts as an entry point
./node_modules/typescript/bin/tsc --noEmit src/index.ts

# if this is a react project, you'll need a jsx arg
./node_modules/typescript/bin/tsc --noEmit --jsx react-jsx -p tsconfig.json
```

The "--noEmit" means that it won't output to a file. The "-p" is for running with a project defined by a tsconfig.json file.

Comment: Neither of your options work

Comment: If that's not working for you, then something else is wrong with your setup. Note that the interface should have a capital 'W'. With this snippet, the TS sandbox will show you that test is fine, but test2 is not:
interface Window {
    test: unknown;
}
window.test; window.test2;

Comment: I deleted my `tsconfig` and am still getting the error. What else can I do?

Comment: For starters, what version of TypeScript are you using? Is this error just showing up in VSCode/some-other-IDE, or has it failed testing with running a TS check directly?

Comment: 4.5.4. It fails in the editor. Idk what TS check is.

Comment: I added notes about running the TS compiler directly from the command line. Try restoring your tsconfig.json file and running the compiler manually to do static analysis.

Answer (score 0):

just add this after import :

declare let window: any;

Comment: Post a descriptive answer, or leave this as a comment.